# WSO2 ESB CONDITIONAL Router For blocking Request bug?

Tags: wso2, conditional-statements, mediator, wso2-esb

im on WSO2 ESB 4.8.1.
I need to block some request if their path match a regular expression. So i've implemented this proxy and these sequences:

In my proxy:

```
  <target>
  <inSequence>        
     <sequence key="MySequence"></sequence>
     <send>
         <endpoint key="epProva"></endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
```

Where MySequence is:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MySequence">        
     <conditionalRouter continueAfter="true">
        <conditionalRoute breakRoute="true" asynchronous="true">
           <condition>
              <match type="url" regex=".*/my/path/.*"></match>
           </condition>
           <target sequence="conf:/BannedListMessage"></target>
        </conditionalRoute>
     </conditionalRouter>     
</sequence>
```

where BannedListMessage is:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">   
   <header name="To" action="remove"></header>
   <property name="HTTP_SC" value="401" scope="axis2"></property>
   <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"></property>
   <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="remove" scope="axis2"></property>
   <payloadFactory media-type="json">
      <format>
        {"code":"401", "unhautorized."}      
     </format>
  </payloadFactory>
  <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
   <respond></reposnd> 
</sequence>
```

If the request addresses an url matching the regex inside the conditional router the only thing the esb has to do is to send a 401 unauthorized message without allowing the request to reach the server.

With this configuration i obtain a wrong behaviour. The esb send me the 401 response BUT the request reach clearly the server (so i suppond that conditional router doesn't prevent the request flow to reach the send to epProva endpoint).

Someone suggested me to use the conditional router in order to obtain a blocking behaviour like the one i want.

Instead if i replace MySequence like in the code below using the switch mediator i get the right behaviour:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">  
     <switch xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" source="get-property('requestURL')">
        <case regex=".*/aggregato/C/sysadmin/mostra_contenuto/.*">
           <sequence key="conf:/BannedListMessage"></sequence>
        </case>
     </switch>
</sequence>
```

So the question is:

- Am i using the conditional router in a wrong way?
- Is this a bug of conditional router?

Answer (score 0):

May be a typo mismatch in your  BannedListMessage

> < respond > < /reposnd >

The usage of the respond mediator is

> < respond / >

Hope it helps
Regards

Comment: i write the correct <respond /> tag... the wso2 editor change it after i save the sequence into <respond> </respond>